# generalize method to fetch and update data using generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

i am trying to create generlize method to updateData when the record gets synced succesfully on the server using realm in xamarin.forms

```
private void updateContactData<T>(Realm realm, IList<T> dataList) where T : RealmObject , IMaster
    {

        realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm =>
        {

            try
            {
                foreach (IMaster data in dataList)
                {
                    IMaster dbData = null;

                    if (data.status.Equals(CREATED))
                    {


                        dbData = tempRealm.Find<T>(data.mId);

                        dbData.Id = data.Id;
                        dbData.syncInfo.isSync = SyncStatus.SYNCED;
                    }
                    else if (data.status.Equals(UPDATED))
                    {

                        // dbData = tempRealm.All<T>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == data.Id);
                        dbData = tempRealm.All<T>().Where(c => c.Id == data.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                        dbData.Id = data.Id;
                        dbData.syncInfo.isSync = SyncStatus.SYNCED;




                    }
                    else if (data.status.Equals(ERROR))
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbData.mId))
                        {
                            dbData = tempRealm.Find<T>(data.mId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dbData = tempRealm.All<T>().Where(c => c.Id == data.Id).FirstOrDefault();


                        }
                        dbData.syncInfo.errorMessage = data.errorMessage;
                        dbData.syncInfo.isSync = SyncStatus.NOT_SYNCED;
                    }


                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {


                Debug.WriteLine("Error hi " + e.Message);
            }


        });
  }
```

one of my models of Contact

```
public class Contact : RealmObject , IMaster
{

    public long contactId { set; get; } = 0;
    [PrimaryKey]
    public String mContactId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();        

    public SyncInfo syncInfo { get; set; }

    public String contactStatus { get; set; }

     public long Id
    {
        get
        {
           return  contactId;
        }

        set
        {
            contactId = value;
        }
    }

    public string mId
    {
        get
        {
            return mContactId;
        }

        set
        {
            mContactId = value;
        }
    }

    public string status
    {
        get
        {
            return contactStatus;
        }

        set
        {
            contactStatus = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface defination of IMaster which will be implemented by all other models

```
public interface IMaster
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    String mId { get; set; }
    SyncInfo syncInfo { get; set; }
    String status { get; set; }
    String errorMessage { get; set; }


}
```

Problem is at line `tempRealm.All<Contact>()` in updateData function , i can not generalize the fetching of data here i.e. i can not use `tempRealm.All<T>()` or `tempRealm.All<IMaster>()` as IMaster is an interface and its not derived from `RealmObject`.

it is possible in android using `T dbInsertable = realm.where((Class<T>)insertable.getClass()).findFirst();`

but not sure how to do in C#

so can anyone suggest how to fix this

`Find<T>` is not working 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand...

try this (adding T constraint to RealmObject):

```
private async void updateData<T>(Realm realm, IList<T> dataList) where T : RealmObject, IMaster, new()
{
   await realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm =>
   {
       foreach (IMaster data in dataList)
       {
           IMaster dbData = null;
           if (data.getStatus().Equals("CREATED"))
           {
               // Problem is here at tempRealm.All<Contact>() i am not able to generlize the fetching of objects
               dbData = tempRealm.Find<T>(data.getmId());

               //you need to put these properties in IMaster (id, syncInfo)
               dbData.id = data.id;
               dbData.syncInfo.isSync = SyncStatus.SYNCED;
           }
       }

   });
}
```

Comment: @Hunt It should work. You added the where constraint, correct? The error you've included the screenshot of shouldn't occur if you've added the where constraint.

Comment: Yes now error is gone i forgot to add where clause , i have another doubt Find function will only find the primary key ?

Comment: Entire visual studio is getting crashed when it encounters `private async void updateData<T>(Realm realm, IList<T> dataList) where T : RealmObject, IMaster, new()
` line

Comment: ` at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
05-20 14:41:19.722 E/mono-rt ( 4658):   at .Database.RealmDB.updateContactData<T_REF> (Realms.Realm,System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<T_REF>) ` crash log

Comment: Tiz i am able to get rid of  those errors now , but the question that i asked is does Find Function only finds the Primary key in model , as for update operation i am finding another field too ?

Comment: for example , for UPDATE operation i am using `dbData = tempRealm.Find<T>(data.getId());` and it seems not working

Comment: try use tempRealm.All<T>().FirstOrDefault(f=>f.id == data.getId()); .Find<T> command search by primarykey only... All<T> command retrieve all entities of type T ... with All<T> command you can use linq after... eg: All<T>().Where(w=> w.fieldyouwanttocheck == data....)

Comment: let me know I'm interested innovia@innovia.me

Comment: @Tiz i have updated the code and i am getting exception i.,e.`Left side of the Equal operator must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm.` when `dbData = tempRealm.All<T>().Where(c => c.Id == data.Id).FirstOrDefault();` statement got executed  in `UPDATED` section

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping Tiz, we have almost resolved it

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this exception is because your `Contact` class has custom getter and setter for the `Id` property which instructs Realm to ignore it when generating the database schema. You can't query by ignored properties because ultimately the query is executed at the database level and it isn't aware of the property. As the current implementation simply proxies one property into another, the easiest solution will be to remove the `contactId` and use `Id` instead.

Comment: so you mean to day i should only search based on id i.e. primary key not on the other properties

Comment: You should only query properties that are automatic - i.e. have the following general structure: `public SomeType MyProperty { get; set; }` (in your example, those are `contactId`, `mContactId`, `contactStatus`, and `syncInfo`. While other properties are supported for reading/writing, they can't be used when querying because Realm isn't aware that they exist.

Comment: that is why i am using only known fields i.e. `contactId, mContactId, contactStatus, and syncInfo` and have exposed it using `IMaster` this way it will come to know rite ?

Comment: No. Realm operates on the class level - i.e. it cares about your classes, not your interfaces. With the `Contact` class, it only cares about its automatic properties - it doesn't know about `Id`, `mId`, and `status`, so when you tell it to execute a query against those, it can't, because those properties don't exist in the database.

Comment: okay so even if `Id , mId and status` are returning the same automatic properties i.e. `mId -> mContactId , Id->contactId , status->contactStatus` it won't work right ? Moreover , then how can we generalize the operations related to entities like cotnact , customer etc , for instance in future if new entity gets introduced then do i need to write a separate method to update the record ( updateContact , updateCustomer) ?

Comment: Is there a reason to have a separate property for the Id? Why not remove `contactId` and use only `Id`?

Comment: `contactId` is a server generated key so when we create a new record from mobile app we wont be having `contactId` when this record gets synced we are updating `contactId` returned from server. while `Id` is a mobile app key for contacts and will be used for new contacts created offline in mobile app

Comment: How are you communicating with the server? If you're using json, you could simply map contactId to Id.